# Вывод данных после каждой итерации цикла while из функции

Tags: php, mysqli, циклы, while

Есть запись типа

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base");
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
//Содержимое таблиц
}
```

Такое сочетание приходится очень часто использовать. Иногда на странице по 5 раз к ряду.
Хочу выйти из положения следующим образом:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base");
function someFunc($res, $parameter){
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row[$parameter]
        }
}
```

После чего:

```
<option><?php echo someFunc($res, 'table_id');?>
```

Но проблема в том, что функция возвращает значение когда полностью пройдет по циклу и соберет все данные. Т.е. получается `<option>все данные таблицы</option>`

Как можно это дело создать правильно, чтобы значение возвращалось из функции после каждой итерации?

Comment: попробуйте добавить ф-цию сброса данных в буфере, но я не уверен, что в данном контексте она отработает: `$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base");
function someFunc($res, $parameter){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row[$parameter];
        ob_flush();
    }
}`

Comment: Вы вообще не возвращаете значение из функции, вы выводите в ней на вывод. а если вы хотите сделать функцию которая бы генерировала много option, то вам придется передавать ей некий шаблон, что бы она этот шаблон интерпретировала и подставляла значения

Answer (score 1):

У вас к тому же лишний `echo` перед вызовом функции, ведь она ничего не возвращает.

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base");
$data = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
function template_print($template, $data){
    foreach($data as $row){
        $trow = $template;
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            $trow = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}',$value,$trow);
        }
        echo $trow;
    }
}
```

После чего:

`<?php template_print('<option value="{{user_id}}">{{user_name}}</option>',$data); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то вы столкнулись с тем, что не можете пройти по одному и тому же результирующему набору несколько раз.

Вариант 1

После выполнения запроса сохраняйте все данные в массив.

```
$array = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

И используйте его

Вариант 2

Сбрасывайте внутренний указатель результирующего набора после каждого итерирования по нему

```
$res->data_seek(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Здесь нужна не функция, а массив.

```
$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM base")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

теперь ты можешь использовать этот массив сколько угодно раз:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    //Содержимое таблиц
}
```

a функции здесь СОВСЕМ не при чем